# When a quantity varies over space, why is it described with a single function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, continuity

Consider a discrete system of particles. For each particle, you can assign a position vector
$$ \vec{r}_n(t) = f_n(t)\hat{x} + g_n(t)\hat{y} $$

There will be $N$ position vectors for the $N$ discrete particles. Now consider an electric field which varies in space and time

$$ \vec{E}(x,y,z,t)$$

Space is a continuous quantity. What I don't understand is why there is only a *single* function to describe a quantity which varies over space. For instance, why don't we have an *infinite and uncountable* number of equations for the electric field due to the *infinite and uncountable* places in space? For ease, I will consider a single dimension of space. Why is it that

$$ \vec{E}_{x_1}(t), \vec{E}_{x_1 + dx}(t), \vec{E}_{x_1 + 2dx}(t) \tag{1}$$
is not the form of the electric field? Instead, it would take the form
$$ \vec{E}(x,t)\tag{2}$$

I ask because equation $(2)$ is much more restrictive that equation $(1)$. Equation $(2)$ is one equation, whereas equation $(1)$ is a set of equations which can take wildly different forms between an $x$ and an $x + dx$ location.

**Question rephrased in a slightly different way:**
Why is that when a label $n$ goes from discrete to continuous, the label is placed within the function $f(n, )$. If the label is discrete, it is place as a subscript $f_n( )$.

**Thoughts:**
$\vec{E}(x,t)$ is restrictive. A single form for all $x$. Do we restrict it like this because we assume something about continuity?

Comment: I think $E(x,t)$ is not as restrictive as you believe. It might not be that $E(x,t)$ has a nice one-line expression in terms of $x$ and $t$.

Comment: How we label it has no bearing on the mathematics. For instance nothing is wrong with considering a sequence as a function $a=a(n), a:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$. 

The notation $E(x,t)$ is just as valid as $E_x(t)$, and it could be that $E(x,t)$ is horribly different and virtually unrelated from $E(x+h,t)$, e.g. maybe $E(x,t)$ is everywhere discontinuous in $x$.

Comment: To amplify the second sentence in @CalvinKhor's comment: If I were asked to define what is meant by a sequence of real numbers, my answer would be that it's a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hm interesting. But isnt something like $E_{x_1}(t) = t^2$, $E_{x_1 + dx}(t) = \sin t$ etc. much more extremely and wildly varying than $E(x,t) = 3x^2\sin t$? In the sense that you have many functions instead of 1. Oh interesting. While we have many functions, all of which vary with time, $E(x,t)$ is a single function but depends on 2 parameters. The loss in complexity in "number of equations" is made up with another parameter

Comment: @CalvinKhor Wait, so if I have a sequence of functions $(f_1(t), f_2(t),...)$ and the index is discrete, it might be possible to construct a single function $f(\text{number}, t)$ of the discrete index. This only works assuming there is some way to combine all the functions together in one compact form? Likewise for the continuous case, I can take my sequence of equations $(1)$ and write this as a function of the continuous index $f(x,t)$, assuming that there is some way to take the sequence and compact it into one equation? When is this possible?

Comment: you seem to be hung up on trying to get a nice compact closed-form for your function. This is not at all required to fit the definition of a function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

In addition, you cannot put the real numbers $x\in \mathbb R$ in a list, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument so functions $E_x(t)$ that are defined for $x\in \mathbb R$ could be much much worse than functions you only define for a countable set of points $x,x+h,x+2h,\dots$

Comment: Also your example $E(x,t)=3x^2\sin t$ is well behaved because you chose it to be so. Compare with something like $E(x,t) = C(x) \sin t$ where $C$ is e.g. the Conway base-13 function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function ? (Why even choose it to be continuous in $t$ for that matter, if you're looking for pathological functions)